# OSX App crashing on load when ParseOSX framework with Dyld Error

Tags: xcode, macos, parse-platform, dyld

I have an OSX app and I have added the ParseOSX sdk. I have followed all the instructions on the quick start page (https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/desktop/osx/existing)

The app is running fine in Xcode (Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)) but when I archive and create a package and install this. I get the following Dyld error;

> Dyld Error Message:
>     Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/ParseOSX.framework/ParseOSX
>     Referenced from: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
>     Reason: image not found

It goes on and lists the Binary Images loaded.

Searching the web I found reference to adding a copy files build phase and adding the parse framework to that with the destination set to Products directory.

So it appears there is a dynamic lib not being installed somewhere.

UPDATE:

I just cleaned the build folder and now the app will not even run under Xcode. I get:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/ParseOSX.framework/ParseOSX
>     Referenced from: /Users/Ants/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjrbgyhzpwnxhiaskxpojqyqxnvh/Build/Products/Debug/Actual.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
>     Reason: image not found

UPDATE 2:

It turns out when you are in the quick start page. If you chose the new app option you get a Xcode project. This compiles. Going through it I can see that there is is a Copy Files step that copies the `ParseOSX.framework` into the Frameworks destination. Tried this is my app and I now get a signing error

`/Users/Ants/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjrbgyhzpwnxhiaskxpojqyqxnvh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/Ants/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hjrbgyhzpwnxhiaskxpojqyqxnvh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/ParseOSX.framework`

Comment: In step 2, when dragging the Parse framework in, did you check the checkbox to copy the file?

Comment: hey @Fosco thanks for the idea, I just re added it and the framework is in the app directory next tot he xcodeprojt file so yeah it looks like it go copied in.

Comment: I just create a test app with only the line `[Parse setApplicationId:@"rterter" clientKey:@"ertert"];` in the Delegate. Get exactly the same error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2xea315dldwqjc/ParseTestApp.zip

Comment: Ok so if I download the new Xcode project I can get that to run. Going to go through the build settings and see what is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things fixed this for me.

First I needed to add a copy files section to the build phases and copy the `ParseOSX.framework` into the Frameworks destination.

And second, I needed to add `--deep` to the "Other Code Signing Flags" in the Code Signing section of Build Settings. It now signs the frameworks being copied it seems.

Comment: Note that the deep code signing option has to have two dashes, so add `--deep` instead.

Comment: @bojand thanks for that, I had actually added `--deep`.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same problem with xcode 6.1. Fixed it by adding `ParseOSX.framework` to "Embedded Binaries" on the general tab of the Targets page.

Comment: I needed to add **both** ParseOX.framework and Bolts.framework as embedded binaries.  Only then would it run without error.

NOTE: I diff'd the remade Parse Xcode project and my own Parse project and the embedded binaries seemed to be the only difference that I could see of any importance. (Disclaimer: I didn't review each difference in depth and I'm not an export on Xcode project files, so YMMV).  But the embedded binaries seem to work.

Comment: Fixed for me too, something broke after upgrading from parse 1.7.5 to 1.9. Like always, there's no update of this lib that goes smooth

Answer (score 1):

I was updating an existing parse project to the newest SDK (1.12.0) using Xcode 7.2 and ran into the same problem.

The solution for me was to set `Runpath Search Paths` to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`.

[image]

I found this by comparing the Starter project from Parse to my project.

Comment: This fixed it for me on Xcode 7.3.1 and Parse 1.12.0. Thanks for the tip.